# Point Cloud Library 1.8 - DepthSense Grabber does not seem to provide RGB data for NaN XYZ points

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, openni

Running the below code with both the Xtion Pro and the DS325 depth cameras gives very different results. The Xtion Pro shows both coloured point cloud and RGB perfectly, whereas the DS325 has many black fuzzy areas in the image, making it unusable for the OpenCV functionality I was intending (after conversion to Mat form).

This link seems to be when XYZ data is captured as NaN. For example, the Xtion Pro shows full RGB fine even when pointed out the window (which makes the majority of XYZ data NaN), whereas doing the same for the DS325 makes almost the whole RGB image show black.

Can someone tell me if this is just an imperfection in the new grabber code? Or is more inherently linked to the differences in mapping for the different hardware?

Running the depthsense viewer application (from primesense SDK) does confirm to me that both depth and full RGB data can be streamed simultaneously, so slightly confused as to why the RGB seems to be being discarded. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Windows, VS2013, PCL 1.8

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/common/time.h>
#include <pcl/console/print.h>
#include <pcl/console/parse.h>
#include <pcl/io/io_exception.h>
#include <pcl/io/openni_grabber.h>
#include <pcl/io/depth_sense_grabber.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/image_viewer.h>

using namespace pcl::console; 
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> PointCloudT; 

std::mutex cloud_mutex; 

void cloud_cb_(const PointCloudT::ConstPtr& callback_cloud, PointCloudT::Ptr& new_cloud_, 
    bool* new_cloud_available_flag) 
{ 
    cloud_mutex.lock(); 
    *new_cloud_ = *callback_cloud; 
    cloud_mutex.unlock(); 
    *new_cloud_available_flag = true; 
} 

void PointXYZRGBAtoCharArray(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr point_cloud_ptr, unsigned char * Image) 
{ 
        for (int i = 0; i < point_cloud_ptr->height; i++) 
        { 
                for (int j = 0; j < point_cloud_ptr->width; j++) 
                { 
                    Image[(i * point_cloud_ptr->width + j) * 3] = point_cloud_ptr->points.at(i * point_cloud_ptr->width + j).r; 
                    Image[(i * point_cloud_ptr->width + j) * 3 + 1] = point_cloud_ptr->points.at(i * point_cloud_ptr->width + j).g; 
                    Image[(i * point_cloud_ptr->width + j) * 3 + 2] = point_cloud_ptr->points.at(i * point_cloud_ptr->width + j).b; 
                } 
        } 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    boost::mutex new_cloud_mutex_; 
    PointCloudT::Ptr cloud(new PointCloudT); 
    bool new_cloud_available_flag = false; 
    std::string device_id = ""; 
    boost::function<void(const typename PointCloudT::ConstPtr&)> f = boost::bind(&cloud_cb_, _1, cloud, &new_cloud_available_flag); 
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::Grabber> grabber; 
    try 
    { 
            grabber.reset(new pcl::OpenNIGrabber); 
            cout << "Using OpenNI Device" << endl; 
    } 
    catch (pcl::IOException& e) 
    { 
            grabber.reset(new pcl::DepthSenseGrabber); 
            cout << "Using DepthSense Device" << endl; 
    } 
    grabber->registerCallback(f); 
    grabber->start(); 

    // Image Viewer 
    pcl::visualization::ImageViewer Imageviewer("Image Viewer"); 
    unsigned char* Image = new unsigned char[3*cloud->height*cloud->width]; 
    Imageviewer.addRGBImage(Image, cloud->width, cloud->height); 

    // Point Cloud Viewer: 
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("PCL Viewer"); 
    viewer.setCameraPosition(0, 0, -2, 0, -1, 0, 0); 

    for (;;) 
    { 
            if (new_cloud_available_flag) 
            { 
                    new_cloud_available_flag = false; 
                    cloud_mutex.lock(); 

                    // Update Image 
                    Imageviewer.removeLayer("rgb_image"); 
                    PointXYZRGBAtoCharArray(cloud, Image); 
                    Imageviewer.addRGBImage(Image,cloud->width,cloud->height); 
                    Imageviewer.spinOnce(); 

                    // Update Point Cloud 
                    viewer.removeAllPointClouds(); 
                    viewer.addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>(cloud); 
                    cloud_mutex.unlock(); 
                    viewer.spinOnce(); 
            } 
    } 
    grabber->stop();
```

}

Comment: It's most likely an implementation problem; I reported this on PCL bug tracker: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1464

Comment: For the record, there is a race condition in your code. It is possible that  when you allocate memory for the image, the cloud callback has not yet been fired, and the cloud dimensions are still uninitialized.

Answer (score 3):

The `DepthSense` grabber receives two streams from the driver: depth and color. They are merged into a single point cloud with colors, which is then returned to the end user. Due to the fact that the two sensors involved (IR and color camera) have a certain displacement and different resolutions (QVGA and VGA respectively), the mapping between depth and color pixels in the streams is not trivial. In fact, for each depth/color frame the camera driver additionally produces so-called UV-map, which can be used to establish correspondences. Unfortunately, it fails to set UV-coordinates for invalid depth pixels, which makes it impossible to find corresponding RGB values for the NaN points.

I would recommend to use the DepthSense SDK directly to access raw RGB images.